# Compiling less files with Grunt

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gruntjs, less

Complete newbie to Grunt here, but basically I am trying to use Grunt to do a couple of things to start with. Minify a JS file, and compile multiple LESS files into one CSS file.

The javascript bit works i.e. my file custom.js compresses to a file called custom.min.js, however the LESS bit doesn't work at all (no errors, just doesn't compile). Can anyone see why this is?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: 'scripts/custom.js',
        dest: 'scripts/custom.min.js'
      }
    },
    less: {
      build: {
        src: 'less/*.less',
        dest: 'style.css'
      }
    },
    watch: {
        files: ['scripts/custom.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify','less']
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

Comment: are you running the command `grunt less`?

Comment: I'm running `grunt watch`, which should run both tasks. Problem is with the less task at the moment, as the JS task runs perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include the call to the less task inside your watch statement, something like:

```
         watch: {
            livereload: {
              options: { livereload: true },
              files: ["public/css/main.css", "public/css/less/*.less", "public/html/*.html", "public/js/*.js"]
            },
            scripts: {
                files: ["public/js/*.js"],
                tasks: ["jshint"]
            },
            less: {
                files: ["public/css/*.less", "public/css/less/*.less"],
                tasks: ["less", "csslint"], 
                options: {
                    nospawn: true
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: false,
                    optimization: 2,
                    cleancss:false,  
                    paths: ["css"],   
                    syncImport: false,
                    strictUnits:false,
                    strictMath: true,
                    strictImports: true,
                    ieCompat: false    
                },
                files: {
                    "public/css/main.css": "public/css/main.less"
                }
            }
        }
```

and then also just register the default task with watch:

```
grunt.registerTask("default", ["express", "open:dev", "watch"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't call the LESS task at all. To call it add the taskname in the registered task

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify','less']);
```

See the documentation to learn more about task registration: http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

EDIT:

I saw you created a `watch` task, so if you don't call the LESS task manually but by watching files, be sure to have executed `grunt watch` in a terminal (and not closed the terminal windows) before modifying the files

Comment: Yes, I am running the `grunt watch` command. The JS tasks works perfectly, but the Less task does not run at all

Answer (score 1):

Move all your less files to one file like this:

Somefile.less:

```
@import '../bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
@import 'site.less';
```

And try the following:

```
less: {
  build: {
    files: {
        'style.css': 'less/somefile.less'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have a file called style.less, which imports all my less files. Problem is that if I change one of the less files, this wouldn't work since I am not explicitly changing the style.less file - just one of the files that is included. If that makes sense?